# Cannot deploy Vue apps on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, deployment

Good afternoon. Can't deploy app to Vue. Everything works fine locally.I make a deployment according to the sample. After clicking on the link given by github ( https://alexsasha1993.github.io/OptimalSity/ )
The console gives the following errors

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () index-1a2d8270.js:1
2. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () index-84e21482.css:1
3. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () favicon.ico:1
4. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () index-84e21482.css:1

Link to the repository itself.
https://github.com/AlexSasha1993/OptimalSity

Did everything according to the tutorial

Answer (score 2):

In `vue.config.js`, you have:

```
module.exports = {
  puplicPath: '/OptimalSity/',
};
```

The option is instead called `publicPath`, with a b.

Comment: Corrected. The same errors(

Comment: You'll have to update and push the `gh-pages` branch as well, not just the `main` branch.

Comment: Like updated.  "git push using:  origin gh-pages
Everything up-to-date"

Comment: I don't know which tutorial you're following, but you'll have to go back and do whatever steps you did earlier to build your app, commit the result `gh-pages` branch, and push that to GitHub since [it only has your first commit still](https://github.com/AlexSasha1993/OptimalSity/tree/gh-pages).

Comment: Everything worked out. Thank you very much!